# How to use Reflection to insert data with mysqli by bind_param method? what is difference of these two arrays?

Tags: php, reflection, mysqli, array-difference, bindparam

As `bind_param($types, $var1, $var2, $var3,..)` method of `mysqli_stmt` class it gets just a series of `$variables` after second parameter (I want to pass array there), and the number of `$variables` is unknown in my case, I want to use Reflection in my `insert($data)` function. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

I do not show the unnecessary part of my function, to avoid confusion...

```
public function insert($data)
{
    $types = 'sss';
    $values = array_values($data);
```

## Removed unrelated code

```
    $ref    = new ReflectionClass($this->stmt);
    $method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");

    //array_unshift($values,$types);                             1-option
    $values = array($types,'alex','alex@code.com','cats');       2-option

    $method->invokeArgs($this->stmt, $values);
    $done = $this->stmt->execute();

    $this->stmt->close();
    return $done;

}
```

As shown in

```
$method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");

$method->invokeArgs($this->stmt, $values);
```

In this part I use Reflection to pass array to second parameter of `bind_param()` method of `$this->$stmt` object.

```
$method->invokeArgs($this->stmt, $values);
```

It doesn`t make mysqli insert into table with 1-option.

But mysqli inserts data when I use 2-option. Why? I have to use with 1-option as number of parameters is unknown.

How can I benefit from Reflection and mysqli it?

What is the difference between those two options(arrays)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use splat operator (PHP version >= 5.6):

```
public function insert($data)
{
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($data), ...$data);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```